# Which version to use as a base for integration?

Tags: karate, reportportal

I see there are list active version of karate available.
Our team develop tool for reporting (reportportal.io) and our users are asking for support of various versions.

As far as i see, there is no back compatibility between 0.9.2 - 0.9.3 - 0.9.4 - 0.9.5RC5
support and track integrations for each of minor versions is overhead.

Could you please updated on any roadmap, ETA and strategy for version compatibility, so we can focus on 1 certain version.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use 0.9.5.RC5 and the `develop` branch in GitHub. The plan is to release 0.9.5 final within a month.